# Run Newman in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, postman, newman

this is my first time using Jenkins for automated test.I've tried to run a test by integrate Newman with Jenkins but I always get the

Console Error

> "Newman : command not found"

as a result,it's make my test failed.

I have looking for some answers on the Internet and some tell me to add a value for Environment variables, but I don't know how to get the exact value to add to this. Please show me where can I get this.I'm using MacOS High Sierra

[image: Jenkins Environment variables]

Comment: also add Console Output from jenkins in your question

Answer (score 18):

1. Install https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs in jenkins
2. In Global Tool Configuration add Nodejs and in "Global npm packages to install" add newman

[image: Global Tool Configuration add Nodejs]

3. In Build Environment use "Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH"
4. In Build add "execute shell" if you are using linux or use "execute windows batch command" if you are on windows  and add your newman command

   For example:

   > newman run
   >   https://www.getpostman.com/collections/631643-f695cab7-6878-eb55-7943-ad88e1ccfd65-JsLv

[image: newman]

Comment: OMG thanks a lot for your help, this have solved my problem

Comment: @NhưNguyễn Note that the postman collections that I use in my answer may fail https://www.getpostman.com/collections/631643-f695cab7-6878-eb55-7943-ad88e1ccfd65-JsLv but newman command will run fine.

Comment: This is a life saver. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

the html extra reporter only worked for me once enabling   'locate executor'  and flag "with ant" as well,  under the provide node & npm option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I had several lines of the text in the Command field. According to advice I used backslashes to make it look pretier and I couldn't create a report with Newman. I got a report only after deleteing the backslashes and writing all information in one line